# getWaitQueueLength throws IllegalArgumentException: Not owner

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing a concurrency problem homework. I have many threads doing specific things and a method which decides when these threads can access a resource.

So my class looks something like this:

```
public class Boss extends ReentrantLock implements Runnable {

    Lock access = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition canTakeOff = access.newCondition();
    Condition canLand = access.newCondition();

    public void accessToLanding(){
            access.lock();
            try{
                if(getWaitQueueLength(canTakeOff) > 0){
                    canTakeOff.notifyAll();
                } else if {
                 /* some other cases */
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                access.unlock();
            }
    }

    public void run(){
        accessToLanding();
    }

    /* Methods which are called by objects of a different class, 
    they are awaiting for the signal from accessToLanding.*/
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not owner
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.getWaitQueueLength(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1789)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.getWaitQueueLength(ReentrantLock.java:720)
```

I've checked the documentation and it says that getWaitQueueLength throws IllegalArgumentException when "the given condition is not associated with this lock" but from what I understand, it is associated in my code.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke

```
getWaitQueueLength(canTakeOff)
```

you are calling

```
this.getWaitQueueLength(canTakeOff)
```

where *this* is your instance of Boss. Despite *canTakeOff* has been declared has a member, it doesn't *belong* to Boss, it is a Condition obtained from *access*

I think that you must change the aforementioned line a bit and use

```
access.getWaitQueueLength(canTakeOff)
```

More info: [Javadoc getWaitQueueLength throws IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#getWaitQueueLength-java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition-)

Comment: When I change it to: `access.getWaitQueueLength(canTakeOff)` it can't resolve method getWaitQueueLength.

Comment: Change access declaration. Write ReentrantLock instead of Lock.

Comment: Now it works. Thank you very much for help, I really appreciate it!